# F# Where is JsonValue AsArray?

Tags: arrays, json, f#

I have:

```
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions

[<EntryPoint>]
let testjson argv =

    let json = """
    {
        "KeyValuePairs": "[{\"Key\" : \"one\", \"Value\" : \"1\"},{\"Key\" : \"two\", \"Value\" : \"2\"}]"
    }
    """

    let info = JsonValue.Parse(json)
    let infoarray = info.AsArray()
```

But I'm getting an error on the last line:

> Error 52  The field, constructor or member 'AsArray' is not defined

even though I'm following the example here:

[F# Data: JSON Parser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html)

in the section, "Using JSON extensions". So, clearly I've got this wrong.But where?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to treat the `JsonValue` itself as an array - it's not, it's an object. It seems you probably want to treat the `KeyValuePairs` property as an array. So try this:

```
let keyValuePairs = info?KeyValuePairs.AsArray()
```

Comment: Hmmm Ok, I get that, I think.  What would I do if I don't know the names of the entries in the JSON in advance?  e.g.  I don't know if there even *is* something called KeyValuePairs.  I only want to see what is in the JSON.  e.g. to print it out for debugging.

Comment: OK, so you don't know if it *does* contain an array? I'm confused about exactly what you're after. Are you starting with a given JSON string? In which case, just print that out for debugging? You might want to rephrase your question.

Comment: Yup, I have a toy example for learning.  When I understand how it all works together,  I'll be getting well-formed JSON from an external source, but it will vary from run to run.  It will likely have a bunch of names and values, then an embedded list with a list of other key/value pairs (hence my toy example) but I can't know in advance the names of the items (though I *will* know the name of the embedded key/value pairs list).  I'll want to save the name/value pairs in a dictionary or something for later use.

Comment: BTW, let keyValuePairs = info?KeyValuePairs.AsArray() shows the same "not defiend" error

Comment: @user1443098 Well that's possibly because `KeyValuePairs` is actually a string in your example.

Comment: but that's my point.  I'm trying to follow the docs.  Which do the same thing unless I'm reading it wrong (highly likely).  OTOH if I copy/paste the exact examples from the docs, they don't work either (same error message)

Comment: @user1443098 Your example has a piece of JSON which contains an object. The one property in that object `KeyValuePairs` is itself a string containing some JSON representing an array. I'm not sure if you meant to nest JSON within JSON like that, but either way, I think you need to amend/rewrite your question and make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: I posted a new question, just using the example from the docs

Answer (score 0):

This an old question but I will leave a reply for those in need.

The mistake was when KeyValuePairs is seen as an Array but instead is a String

```fs
let json = """ {"KeyValuePairs": "[{\"Key\" : \"one\", \"Value\" : \"1\"},{\"Key\" : \"two\", \"Value\" : \"2\"}]"} """

let info = JsonValue.Parse(json)

let infoarray = info?KeyValuePairs.AsString()

let newinfo = JsonValue.Parse infoarray

printfn "%A" (newinfo.[0]?Key.AsString()) // prints "one"
```

Hope this was helpful!

Cheers